# TLS mail authentication over keytool problems

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, keytool

Trying to register mail certificate for TLS authentication:

```
keytool -import -file C:\Users\martin\"Automation Projects"\RemedySOAPWebService\src\resources\mail.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\security" -alias mail
```

Error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin>keytool -import -file C:\Users\martin\"Automation Projects"\RemedySOAPWebService\src\resources\mail.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\lib\security" -alias mail
Illegal option:  Projects\RemedySOAPWebService\src\resources\mail.cer -keystore C:\Program
```

I get this jumbled up error message. What's going on here?

Comment: Please do not edit a question to include the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the directories that contain spaces.

Comment: So how did you magically get past the keytool runtime error which you have now removed from your question and changed it to a completely different problem?